# Issue while modifying and importing the manually content type data

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a scenario like this:

I am using Feeds Importer to import one content type data. I am using GUID field as the unique field. Also, I am exporting these all the nodes of this content type using Views into a .csv file.

My problem is that users can create nodes using the Feeds Importer and also manually in the Drupal admin console.

While I export the nodes of the content type, it contains all nodes (manually created nodes and Feeds imported nodes). There will be no GUID for the manually created nodes.

In this case, how can I resolve the issue of re-import of this data into the Drupal tool?

Is there a way to update the GUID field in the database whenever a new node of this type is created? This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Universally Unique IDentifier](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) and use it as GUID.it is not required you create GUID field in most of time `Nid` is good choice  as GUID mapper.

**Universally Unique IDentifier** Description :

> This module provides an API for adding universally unique identifiers
>   (UUID) to Drupal objects, most notably entities. Features in Drupal 7
>   version Automatic UUID generation
>
> UUIDs will be generated for all core entities. An API is provided for
>   other modules to enable support for custom entities. UUID API for
>   entities, properties and fields
>
> With this unified API you can load entities with entity_uuid_load() so
>   that all supported properties and fields are made with UUID
>   references. You can also save entities formatted this way with
>   entity_uuid_save() (depends on Entity API). Export entities to use as
>   default/demo content
>
> The integration with Features module provides the ability to export
>   UUID enabled entities with intact dependencies and references to other
>   entities. This functionality depends on Deploy module 7.x-2.0-alpha1
>   (soon to be released) and is probably the most robust way for
>   installation profiles and distributions to provide demo content!

Comment: In that case, if user adds new rows into the excel file and if the user uploads the file, how will the UUID gets updated for the newly created nodes?

Comment: Apologize me, what you want to do?
first import data form csv to  site, then again export them, add some row to data and again import it to site?

Comment: Yes. This is my requirement.

Comment: @Kiran  why  don't  try incremental method?
just add new items to file and import them, why you export old ones?

Comment: @Kiran Do you have custom module ?

Comment: Currently, I am exporting the nodes using Views module and it is giving me null GUID for the nodes which are created manually. I am exporting all these nodes to make some changes in the data. I don't have any custom module for this. If I manually update the GUID for the nodes created manually, it will create new nodes instead of updating the nodes.

Comment: @Kiran `UUID` help to what you want. take look at https://www.drupal.org/node/1800730